# Should I run my dishwasher from time to time?

Tags: dishwasher

Ok, this is probably a stupid question, however, here it is.

I have not used my dishwasher for more than a year because I wash everything by hands. The dishwasher was used before for ~4 years by previous owners. Now, I am thinking if It is recommended to run it from time to time or there is no difference at all?

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: If you want to keep it running well, should run it every so often.  It would also probably give you extra storage space, if you don't use it.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks for the advice. Is there anything in the dishwasher that can deteriorate if it's not used ?

Comment: Seals can dry out on some, but most should be okay.

Comment: You need to run it at least every couple of months, or the trap will go dry and let in sewer gas. That is true for anything with a drain.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica thanks, it drains to my kitchen sink, so I guess that should not be a problem .

Comment: If you are never going to use it as a dishwasher again, then do not need to run it.  Running it once so often will tend keep things from drying out and keep from seizing, if you want to keep it as a dishwasher, instead of a storage cabinet.

Comment: you should use it anyway, it saves time and money compared to hand washing, which wastes a lot of water.